# Include additional object when archiving with NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

I'm trying to archive a tree of objects using `NSKeyedArchiver`. All nodes in the tree support `NSCoding`, but I don't have access to the source code, so I can't change anything. However, I'd like to include an additional `NSString` with some of the nodes during encoding. When unarchiving, I'd like to get that string (if available) and do some additional setup depending on what that string is.

How could I do this in an elegant way? I thought about substituting a subclass when encoding, implementing the additional encoding in the subclass. And make the subclass' `initWithCoder:` return an instance of the superclass, properly initialized and setup. The problem with this is, that I might have "real" subclasses of the node classes in my tree. And if such a subclass is encoded, the substitution wouldn't work. Or at least I don't see how.

Currently I'm looking into subclassing NSKeyedArchiver, but I'm not sure where I could inject anything or if this is a good approach at all.

Comment: Instead of subclassing why don't use NSKeyedArchiver delegate to decorate the behaviour of `NSKeyedArchiver` to get the work done? Probably this `– archiver:willEncodeObject:` method could be of help.

Comment: I thought that was just a notification to keep track of the progress, but not a way to influence the process. I'll try that, thanks.